# Is there any short way to solve a system Ax=B, when A is [3x3xN], i.e more then one matrix?

Tags: matlab

I want to try and implement it without a loop...

I have A, as A[3x3xN] or [3,3,N] and for each N it is a different matrix.

and B as [3x1xN] ofcourse...

How can I solve it without doing a loop and make A^-1 * B every time ?

Comment: Instead of `[3x3xN]` and `[3x1xN]`, why not `[3x3N]` and `[3xN]`? If you're looking for the same `x` every iteration, it just becomes a larger matrix.

Comment: I need to solve N equations, each one is different. each one is given by Ax=B with the suitible A and B

Comment: In that case, you'll have to solve them separately, which means you'll end up computing A^-1*B for every equation anyway. @petrichor seems to have a concise way of doing so in their answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Z = cellfun(@(a,b) a\b, ... %# Solve for each pair
            num2cell(A,[1 2]), ... %# Make a cell array containing each slice
            num2cell(B,[1 2]), ... %# Make a cell array containing each slice
            'UniformOutput',false);
Z = cat(3,Z{:}); %# Merge the results to a 3x1xN array
```

Please see [`num2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html#btj8y8e-1) and [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) documentation for further details on the functions used.

Let us compare its speed to a for loop:

```
clc, clear

N = 100000;
D = 10;
A = rand(D,D,N);
B = rand(D,1,N);

tic
Z = cellfun(@(a,b) a\b, ...
            num2cell(A,[1 2]),num2cell(B,[1 2]),'UniformOutput',false);
Z = cat(3,Z{:});
toc

tic
Z2 = zeros(D,1,N);
for i = 1:N
    Z2(:,:,i) = A(:,:,i) \ B(:,:,i);
end
toc

all(isequal(Z,Z2))
```

My results are as follows:

```
Elapsed time is 2.130507 seconds.
Elapsed time is 1.306873 seconds.
```

I tried it with different `D` values and got always similar ratios. Jonas' bet is correct!

Comment: I bet that a loop will be a lot faster.

Comment: @YNWA: cooler and more readable (=maintainable) are not always synonymous!